# Copying Arrays onto another Array?

Tags: java, arrays, copying

I have a question: I want an array that I want to copy over to another array so that when the user inputs something in the first array and wants to add more items (in another array) it doesn't completely erase what the user had originally.

Here's my code:

```
    System.out.println("Input up to '10' numbers for current array: ");

    int[] array1;
    array1 = new int[10];

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println((i+1)+": ");
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input == 0) {
            break;

        } else {
            array1[i] = input;
        }

        int[][] array2 = new int[2][];
        for (i = 0; i <3; i ++){

            array2[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array1[i], array1[i]);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The second part I'm trying to loop the first array into the second array.

Comment: Do you have to use an array? I'd use an ArrayList, which just grows when you add data to it.

Comment: You explained your task and showed some code, but you didn't tell us what's the problem with your current solution. Please elaborate on what your question actually is. :)

Comment: `array2[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array1[i], array1[i]);` - what are you trying to do here? This method doesn't take two ints.

Comment: @Eran, I was trying something random, I guess. I'm still not that great at coding in Java.

Comment: I want to try and create a second array from the inputted numbers in the first array using a loop. Not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: @Jeremy Your current code makes no sense. I just noticed that the loops are nested and you are using the same variable - `i` - in both. Are you trying to create multiple copies of the source array (one copy after each element is assigned to the original array)?

Comment: @Eran, So, should it not be nested? Here's what I'm trying to do: 1) When the user inputs numbers (up to 10) in the first array, and wants to input more numbers, 2) a second array is created -- which copies all those numbers from array 1 to array 2. The new numbers are then added onto array 1. If this makes any sense. :/

Comment: What should happen when the user gets to 20 inputs?

Comment: @David Wallace, well for now I'm just trying to implement the copying of arrays into something small. If I can guess correctly, you can have more than 10 inputs for an `int[] variable;`, correct?

Comment: OK, your current code does something a bit strange.  Every time the user enters a number, you're trying three times to copy the array.  That's almost certainly not what you want.  I think you need to sit down with pencil and paper and work out exactly what the flow through the different parts of your program should be, before you write too much more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that your problem is save the input in a first array with a maximum, but with the possibility to quit if you put zero. Then copy the data from array1 into an array2 with the size of the data inserted. Is it correct?

Well, I modified your code to show you the use of the instruction Arrays.copyOf (you need to import java.util.Arrays). 
  The point is, that you need to write the copy instruction out of the for loop. I recommend you to use the length property instead the plain number in the range of the for loop. Also, if you want to copy the entire array1 including zeros into array2, replace the second parameter:

```
        array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);
```

This is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Input up to '10' numbers for current array: ");

        //Declaring array1 and scanner
        int[] array1 = new int[10];
        int i;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Your loop to ask for data into array1
        for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            System.out.print((i+1)+": ");
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                array1[i] = input;
            }
        }

        //Copy array1 into array2
        int[] array2 = new int[i];

        for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
            array2[j] = array1[j];
        }

        //array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array1, i);
        // array2 = copy(array1, i);

        //Print out the second array, only for test
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(array2[j]);
        }

        scan.close();
}


public static int[] copy(int [] source, int len){
    int [] target = new int[len];
    for(int i=0; i<len;i++){
        target[i] = source[i];
    }

    return(target);
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out on this. I was looking at the web for some examples and I kind of don't want to import anything into the code. How can I do this without importing tools? I want to try and code the code above using basic concepts.

Comment: Well, create your own copy method (I modified the example), and replace the code  array2 = copy(array1, i);

Comment: I didn't understand this part `array2 = copy(array1, i);`

Comment: I haven't used a call method before from creating a new class within the code. Can I do something without using a call method? Sorry if it seems like I'm asking too many questions. Trying to understand the concepts of coding in JAVA.

Comment: Use the same code of the method but directly in your main code. I modified the example again. You could see that the result is the same but without a method:  int[] array2 = new int[i];

        for(int j=0; j<i;j++){
            array2[j] = array1[j];
        }

Comment: The point is that you need a simple for to copy the data from one array to another, but it is important initialize the array to the correct size, in this case then counter "i" which have the total items inserted by the user. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Use System.arrayCopy() to perform this .